# getting layout of user using API

Tags: page-layout, account, sobject, contact, describesobject

I am using this link [to get the layout.](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index_Left.htm#CSHID=resources_sobject_layouts.htm%7CStartTopic=Content%2Fresources_sobject_layouts.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp)

I am using a REST client,
Here is my request

```
https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/data/v28.0/sobjects/Global/describe/layouts/

Authorization: Bearer 5Aep8617VFpoP.M.4uMiWNO.xvIHpOSt0d9NbH755xYRS.qhk32l66qvNa0fz7c4y5YtX9DAplJ9VCm8l0rnIQX
```

but in each response , I am getting

```
[1]
0:  {
message: "Session expired or invalid"
errorCode: "INVALID_SESSION_ID"
}
```

I am logged in SF as well, can you tell me what is wrong, I am sure the token is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The session token looks weird. Normally they start with 00Dxxx!... Where xxx is the org's unique id. I suspect what you have is an authorization or refresh token, which you need to trade for a session token. Check the docs for the refresh token and web server flow for more information.

Assuming that's correct, make sure you're at the right end point. It is included in a successful login attempt. Each server will only recognize its own session tokens, and not from any other server. Again, refer to the documentation above for more info.

Comment: @sdcfox yes I have refresh token, how to get the sessio token?

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=remoteaccess_oauth_refresh_token_flow.htm&language=en_US will get you where you want to go. Basically, you need to call /services/oauth2/token with the appropriate parameters in order to exchange your refresh token for an access token.